# Is there a solution to a react installation error?

Tags: reactjs, terminal, coding-style, create-react-app, npm-install

I tried running react-create-app (app_name) but ended up having a problem. I also tried cleaning the cache, --force, same issue. I tried deleting the node module file I previously had and reinstalling[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGs6v.png) but still ended up with the same problem.

I need to install the react app to begin working on the project.

Comment: try with `sudo npx`

Comment: For anyone that encounters this same problem. The solution which ended up working for me was the use of "sudo npx"

sudo npx create-react-app app_name

Comment: This is not a formal solution, I've shared some steps to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

**Change the permission of npm's cache directory**

1. Find the path of npm cache

   `$ npm config get cache`

   This will give you, for osx `/Users/name/.npm`
2. Change the ownership to current user

   `$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get cache)`

   This changes the permission to the subfolders also.

More on [Fixing npm EACCESS errors](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)